# git push error: RPC failed; curl 52 OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection was reset, errno 10054

Tags: git, git-bash, git-push

While pushing code to the branch from `Git Bash` terminal to a repository I am getting the following error:

[image]

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This message means that something between Git and the remote server caused the network connection to be unexpectedly reset.  This should not happen in normal situations, but sometimes it does due to various issues:

- If you are using a non-default antivirus or firewall, these can tamper with network connections and cause problems like this.  If you're using one of these, try completely uninstalling these, rebooting, enabling Windows Defender and Windows Firewall, and then trying again.
- This can also be caused by other types of proxies or TLS middleboxes.  You can try connecting from a network that doesn't use these to see if it fixes the problem.
- This can be caused by various network problems or (in some countries) intentional action on the part of your ISP.  You can do some standard network diagnostics to see if you see things like packet loss or other network problems.

In general, setting `http.postBuffer` is not effective for this problem, [as outlined in the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-postbuffer).  If it does work, then that means you either have a transient network problem, and it just happened to work that time, or you have something tampering with your data, and it's broken, and you should remove that program or device from your system or network.  So one of the above issues is likely the cause nevertheless.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm. Does your commit have large files? Have you set your post buffer to a higher number? It defaults (IIRC) to 50mb.

Try:

```
$git config http.postBuffer 5000000000
```

If that's not it, then it's still something about your connection that is causing the remote to close your connection without reading the contents. You might check your firewall connections, or ensure the remote doesn't automatically refuse whatever you are sending over.

Comment: Yes, commit have large files but it does not seem to be an issue so far until I got the error today suddenly. I have already used `git config http.postBuffer 524288000` but it did not work though.

Comment: Please read [the Git FAQ entry on `http.postBuffer`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-postbuffer) and why it should not be needed, and why if it is needed the problem is better fixed elsewhere.